# Get parent directory of file as string c++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, directory, c++-cli

I'm using Managed C++.
I need to extract the parent directory  after OpenFileDialog returns the String^ file path.

```
System::String^ filestring = openFileDialog1->FileName;
```

The method that microsoft uses is `Directory::GetParent` but this must be saved as

```
System::IO::DirectoryInfo^ WhyIsThisNotAString = Directory::GetParent(filestring)
```

I need to somehow convert from `DirectoryInfo^` to `String^`.

I have also tried this after OpenFileDialog is called, but it does not work:

```
String^ CurrDir = Directory::GetCurrentDirectory();
```

Or if there is a better way to extract the parent directory that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the FullName property:

```
System::String^ directoryFullName=Directory::GetParent(filestring)->FullName;
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx)?

The `DirectoryInfo` class has a `FullName` property with the following description:

> Gets the full path of the directory or file.

Comment: I have been RTFM, for about 20 minutes, but searching through msdn references can be a bit time consuming. The point of this website is to HELP people who are not as knowledgeable. Not be a condescending prick.

Comment: Actually, MSDN is a *reference*: it is designed to help you when you *already know where* to find what you're looking for. If you don't feel you are knowledgeable enough, you should go out and buy a book on .NET that has a broader view and points to different classes. Those two and Google are three complementary views of the same information.

Answer (score 1):

Check out System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName on MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx

String^ folderName = System::IO::Path::GetDirectoryName(filestring);